# Include page name in title?

Tags: html, title

Should a `title` include the page's name, for example on an "About us" page:

> About us | Discover the history of our online store | Amazon.com

Or should I just use the keyword filed:

> Discover the history of our online store | Amazon.com

Comment: If you are going to leave anything out of the title, it should be the description.   Why wouldn't you use "About Amazon.com" or "About Us | Amazon.com" as the page title?   "Discover the history of our online store" is a very poor page title.

Comment: This may help you:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/title

Answer (score 4):

If you are not making your document title excessively long by including the name of the page, then yes, you would be well-advised to include it.

Including the page name in the document title will contribute to giving a helpful page descriptor both for humans and for non-human user-agents

From a human reader perspective, it might be useful to keep more explicit detail at the start of the title and push the more general detail towards the end of the title (as in your example above).

So you could have something like:

`<title>What we Sell, Our Vision and Our Story | About Us &bull; OnlineBookshop.com</title>`

Comment: Nice! The only time it makes sense to put a page name in a title is for the few pages that have special consideration which would be home, about, and contact.